# Crystal Report Record Selection Formula to Eliminate Duplicate Rows

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a view in oracle database. The view represents the following data. There are some duplicate data is available in that view. I need to have these duplicate data also. The data represents are:

```
** *Col_1     Col_2     Col_3      Col_4***
    0001      Apple     Nasir      Cat
    0001      Apple     Nasir      Rat
    0002      Orange    Babul      Cat
    0003      Apple     Tutul      Cow
    0004      Banana    Jasim      Goat
    0004      Banana    Jasim      Goat
```

Now I have used this view as data source of my Crystal Report. I am showing only Col_1, Col_2, Col_3 columns record in my crystal report. So the crystal report is showing the following data.

```
  **Col_1      Col_2         Col_3**       
    0001       Apple         Nasir     
    0001       Apple         Nasir     
    0002       Orange        Babul     
    0003       Apple         Tutul     
    0004       Banana        Jasim     
    0004       Banana        Jasim
```

But I want to omit the duplicate data. So that the Crystal Report only shows the following data.

```
**Col_1    Col_2     Col_3**       
  0001     Apple     Nasir     
  0002     Orange    Babul     
  0003     Apple     Tutul     
  0004     Banana    Jasim
```

Can anyone help me to write a **crystal report record selection formula** so that I may able to show the data as required? I am using Crystal Report 2008.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution. Group by the all fields needed to show in the report. Then hide the details section. Then it is possible to show the distinct/ unique records.

All the best.

Comment: that's what I suggested you to do in my answer

Answer (score 2):

you can directly use the option `Select Distinct Records` available in `Database` menu... which will only select and show distinct records.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a formula that include those 3 columns(something like this Col_1 + Col_2 +  Col_3), create a group based on that formula and place those 3 fields in that group.

Comment: can you give me a sample

Comment: the sample is on my answer. If you want to do the change on crystal report layout use my advice. If you want to filter your data using a query @Siva posted the best answer.